# How can I assign an output to a function call in python?

Tags: function, python-3.x, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I know I can't necessarily assign values to function call, so how would I assign an output to that function call? I've built a function that checks if a location (row,col) is valid in puzzle(list). I built another function that returns the value at that location. I am now building a third function that calls those two functions to set a value at a specific location, if that value was initially none. If the value was able to be set, it needs to return True. If the value was not None, it doesn't need to be set and it should return false.

For example:

> set_location([[1]],    1,  (0,0)) → False
>
> set_location([[None]], 1,  (0,0)) → True # puzzle  is  now [[1]]

My code is the following:

```
def is_valid_location(loc,puzzle):
    x,y=loc
    return x in range(len(puzzle[0])) and y in range(len(puzzle))

def get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc):
    val_loc=puzzle[loc[0]][loc[1]]
    return val_loc

def set_location(puzzle,value,loc):
    if is_valid_location(loc,puzzle)== True:
        if get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc) != None:
            return False
        else:
             if get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc) == None:
                 get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc)= value
                 return True
```

Obviously the problem is this line:

> get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc)= value

But I'm not sure how else to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Would your solution be:

```
value = get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc)
```

Comment: No. The initial value at location will be None. I need to set that empty location to a specific value.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, once you have the _value_ that you want to place at that location, you can set it by: puzzle[col][row] = value

Comment: The location has to be defined.

Comment: In trying to build your puzzle/board, with the intention to use a list of lists, you would need to create placeholders for each space in your puzzle. puzzle = [ [row1PH , row2PH , ...] , [row1PH , row2PH , ...] , ...] for m columns and n rows.

Comment: I'm still not following.

Comment: So in your program each place holder value would be set to None

Comment: Python doesn't know how many columns and rows that you want, so you will specify those when you set your _puzzle_ variable. With a 2-x-2 matrix (puzzle) you say _puzzle_ =  [ [None , None] , [None , None] ]

Comment: So then you can say `puzzle[0][0] == None` which is True and then you can set it with your value.

Comment: What dimensions do you want the puzzle?

Comment: I have various test cases with various puzzle lengths